# Zend Framework double class menu active 

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I make a menu with Zend_Navigation.
The trouble is that I detect a few times "active menu" that is, the "li" of the current page.

Here is my navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<nav>   
    <home>
        <label>Accueil</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
    </home> 

    <search>
        <label>Riads</label>
        <controller>search</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <params>
            <q>allriads</q>
        </params>
    </search>

    <last>
        <label>Dernières Minutes</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
    </last>

    <promotion>
        <label>Promotions</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
    </promotion>

    <groupes>
        <label>Groupes</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
    </groupes>

    <contact>
        <label>Contact</label>
        <controller>apropros</controller>
        <action>contact</action>
    </contact>

</nav>
```

Here is the code in my bootstrap

```
/**
 * @return Zend_Navigation
 */
protected function _initNavigation()  
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $this->_view->navigation(new Zend_Navigation($config));
    $activeNav = $this->_view->navigation()->findByController('index');
    $activeNav->active = true;
    $activeNav->setClass("active");
}
```

Here is the HTML generated

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="active">
    <a class="active" href="/v2/">Accueil</a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <a href="/v2/search/index/q/allriads">Riads</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">Dernières Minutes</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Promotions</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Groupes</a>

</li>
<li>
    <a href="/v2/apropros/contact">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

The good code must be :

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li>
    <a href="/v2/">Accueil</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="/v2/search/index/q/allriads">Riads</a>
</li>
[...]
```

What is the solution?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

change your Bootrasp.php:

```
public function _initNavigation()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Navigation', $navigation);
}
```

In your layout.phtml

```
<?=$this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial(null, 'shared/menu.phtml')?>
```

in the partial file: */application/views/shared/menu.phtmt* write this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <?
    foreach ($this->container as $page) :
    /** @var $page Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc */
    ?>
        <li class="<?=$page->isActive(true) ? 'active' : ''?>">
            <a href="<?=$page->getHref()?>"><b><?=$page->label?></b></a>
        </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

By doing this, it inhibits the html generated by Zend_Navigator, but you decide to generate the html!
I hope to check out was of help!