# Zend Navigation : url of current page instead url of my xml files

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have a navigation Zend_Navigation. It allows me to detect the current page.

- The problem is that some of my pages:
- All links are replaced by "current page"
- All labels are good

Here is a bizarre result. You can see my site: http://www.riads-marrakech.org/v2/ficheriad/detail/21-riad-croix-berbere.html

If you watch the top menu (Accueil / Riads ...), they all target the "current page".

Here is my bootstrap :

```
/**
 * @return Zend_Navigation
 */
protected function _initNavigation()  
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Navigation', $navigation);

}
```

The menu is called in my layout like this:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial(null, 'templates/menu.phtml')?>
```

Here is my navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<nav>   
    <home>
        <label>Accueil</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
    </home> 

    <search>
        <label>Riads</label>
        <controller>search</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <params>
            <q>allriads</q>
        </params>
    </search>

    <last>
        <label>Dernières Minutes</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
    </last>

    <promotion>
        <label>Promotions</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
    </promotion>

    <groupes>
        <label>Groupes</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
    </groupes>

    <contact>
        <label>Contact</label>
        <controller>apropos</controller>
        <action>contact</action>
    </contact>

</nav>
```

And as you can see, the navigation generated in this link is :

```
<ul id="nav-search">
        <li>

        <a href="/v2/ficheriad/detail/21-riad-croix-berbere.html">Accueil</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/v2/ficheriad/detail/21-riad-croix-berbere.html">Riads</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Dernières Minutes</a>

    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Promotions</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Groupes</a>
    </li>
        <li>

        <a href="/v2/ficheriad/detail/21-riad-croix-berbere.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

instead of

```
    <ul id="nav-search">
        <li class="active">

        <a href="/v2/">Accueil</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/v2/search/index/q/allriads">Riads</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Dernières Minutes</a>

    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Promotions</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Groupes</a>
    </li>
        <li>

        <a href="/v2/apropos/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for your support coming

## EDIT : add the menu.phtml

```
<ul id="nav-search">
<?
foreach ($this->container as $page) :
/** @var $page Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc */
?>
    <li<?=$page->isActive(true) ? ' class="active"' : ''?>>
        <a href="<?=$page->getHref()?>"><?=$page->label?></a>
    </li>
<? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

## edit 25/11/2011 : add source code of the view helper LinkRewrite

```
/**
 * Doctrine inflector has static methods for inflecting text
 *
 * The methods in these classes are from several different sources collected
 * across several different php projects and several different authors. The
 * original author names and emails are not known
 *
 * @package     Doctrine
 * @subpackage  Inflector
 * @license     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-license.php LGPL
 * @link        www.phpdoctrine.org
 * @since       1.0
 * @version     $Revision: 3189 $
 * @author      Konsta Vesterinen <kvesteri@cc.hut.fi>
 * @author      Jonathan H. Wage <jonwage@gmail.com>
 */

class Default_View_Helper_LinkRewrite extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

/**
 * Check if a string has utf7 characters in it
 *
 * By bmorel at ssi dot fr
 *
 * @param  string $string
 * @return boolean $bool
 */
public function seemsUtf8($string)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        if (ord($string[$i]) < 0x80) continue; # 0bbbbbbb
        elseif ((ord($string[$i]) & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
        elseif ((ord($string[$i]) & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
        elseif ((ord($string[$i]) & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
        elseif ((ord($string[$i]) & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
        elseif ((ord($string[$i]) & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
        else return false; # Does not match any model

        for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) 
        { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
            if ((++$i == strlen($string)) || ((ord($string[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Remove any illegal characters, accents, etc.
 *
 * @param  string $string  String to unaccent
 * @return string $string  Unaccented string
 */
public function unaccent($string)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) ) 
    {
        return $string;
    }

    if ($this->seemsUtf8($string))
    {
        $chars = array(
        // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
        chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(135) => 'C', chr(195).chr(136) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(137) => 'E', chr(195).chr(138) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(139) => 'E', chr(195).chr(140) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(141) => 'I', chr(195).chr(142) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(143) => 'I', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
        chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
        chr(195).chr(159) => 's', chr(195).chr(160) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(161) => 'a', chr(195).chr(162) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(163) => 'a', chr(195).chr(164) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(165) => 'a', chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
        chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(177) => 'n', chr(195).chr(178) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(179) => 'o', chr(195).chr(180) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(181) => 'o', chr(195).chr(182) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(185) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(186) => 'u', chr(195).chr(187) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(188) => 'u', chr(195).chr(189) => 'y',
        chr(195).chr(191) => 'y',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
        chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
        chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
        chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
        chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
        chr(197).chr(148) => 'R', chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(150) => 'R', chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(152) => 'R', chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(154) => 'S', chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(156) => 'S', chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(158) => 'S', chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
        chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
        chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's',
        // Euro Sign
        chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E',
        // GBP (Pound) Sign
        chr(194).chr(163) => '',
        'Ã„' => 'Ae', 'Ã¤' => 'ae', 'Ãœ' => 'Ue', 'Ã¼' => 'ue',
        'Ã–' => 'Oe', 'Ã¶' => 'oe', 'ÃŸ' => 'ss');

        $string = strtr($string, $chars);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8
        $chars['in'] = chr(128).chr(131).chr(138).chr(142).chr(154).chr(158)
        .chr(159).chr(162).chr(165).chr(181).chr(192).chr(193).chr(194)
        .chr(195).chr(196).chr(197).chr(199).chr(200).chr(201).chr(202)
        .chr(203).chr(204).chr(205).chr(206).chr(207).chr(209).chr(210)
        .chr(211).chr(212).chr(213).chr(214).chr(216).chr(217).chr(218)
        .chr(219).chr(220).chr(221).chr(224).chr(225).chr(226).chr(227)
        .chr(228).chr(229).chr(231).chr(232).chr(233).chr(234).chr(235)
        .chr(236).chr(237).chr(238).chr(239).chr(241).chr(242).chr(243)
        .chr(244).chr(245).chr(246).chr(248).chr(249).chr(250).chr(251)
        .chr(252).chr(253).chr(255);

        $chars['out'] = "EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy";

        $string = strtr($string, $chars['in'], $chars['out']);
        $doubleChars['in'] = array(chr(140), chr(156), chr(198), chr(208), chr(222), chr(223), chr(230), chr(240), chr(254));
        $doubleChars['out'] = array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th');
        $string = str_replace($doubleChars['in'], $doubleChars['out'], $string);
    }

    return $string;
}

/**
 * Convert any passed string to a url friendly string. Converts 'My first blog post' to 'my-first-blog-post'
 *
 * @param  string $text  Text to urlize
 * @return string $text  Urlized text
 */
public function linkRewrite($text)
{
    // Remove all non url friendly characters with the unaccent function
    $text = $this->unaccent($text);

    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower'))
    {
        $text = mb_strtolower($text);
    } else {
        $text = strtolower($text);
    }

    // Remove all none word characters
    $text = preg_replace('/\W/', ' ', $text);

    // More stripping. Replace spaces with dashes
    $text = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Z^a-z^0-9^\/]+/', '-',
                       preg_replace('/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/', '\1_\2',
                       preg_replace('/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/', '\1_\2',
                       preg_replace('/::/', '/', $text)))));

    return trim($text, '-');
}

}
```

I call in my view like that :
`<a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/ficheriad/detail/<?php echo $oResult["etablissement_id"]?>-<?php echo $this->linkRewrite($oResult["etablissement_nomAMarrakech"])?>.html"><?php echo $oResult["etablissement_descriptifCourt"]?></a>`

Comment: please show me this file: `templates/menu.phtml`

Comment: This is very strange! It should work! The code is correct!
Try to debug the `$page->isActive(true)`

Comment: Me too, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: maybe it's the fault of the mod rewrite! Try doing a test disabling the mod rewrite please!

Comment: Can I disable the mod rewrite only for one vhost ? I've got a lot of website on my dedicated server and they use mod rewrite.

Comment: But the mod rewrite configurations on a single site does not have to file .htaccess single site?

Comment: Oh... yeah. Sorry, wake up, I am not very powerful XD! My htaccess is clear. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)|$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: try to comment this two line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)|$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Same problem. The nav links gets always the current url :s

Comment: Sorry! But if you view this page: http://www.riads-marrakech.org/v2/ The menu show is correct! If the controller `ficheriad` is not exsist in config nav is normal that not find active node! ;)

Comment: Yes, this is I say ! The nav works on each page until on ficheriad controller. My question is... How can I do work my nav ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit this:

```
<home>
    <label>Accueil</label>
    <controller>index</controller>
</home>
```

with this:

```
<home>
    <label>Accueil</label>
    <controller>index</controller>
    <pages>
        <ficheriad>
            <controller>ficheriad</controller>
            <action>detail</action>
        </ficheriad >
    </pages>
</home>
```

Comment: This is very strange!!! You're probably doing some redirection or route that you have set some time to ignore!

Comment: oh wow, if you visit this page: http://www.riads-marrakech.org/v2/ The navigation right work!!!!

Comment: is this `21-riad-croix-berbere.html` that create the problem!!! How generate this: `21-riad-croix-berbere.html`?

Comment: I've created a view helper based on doctrine urlize. It edit my first post to add the code

Comment: I suppose that this is problem! Try you remove use this view helper!

Comment: I remove my helper. The problem is the same... You help me a first time for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169382/zend-framework-double-class-menu-active

Comment: Really strange! It is true! So?

Comment: So maybe, if we take the first code in the question above... I've take it again, but the current url is the same for the ficheriad controller. I think the problem is because the controller isn't exists in the navigation.xml :s

Comment: I do not think this is the problem, the problem is that when you go to a page using the controller ficheriad, in the html generated href all change with the url and this is not normal behavior! :S

Comment: Would you want to see the ficheriad code ? This is not my code (I get the project and I try to correct the [...bad words X...] code of the last webdev :s

Comment: The view helper you posted does is clean up the post title, you should find the code having to queue at the baseurl string.html! In my opinion it is he who creates problems!

Comment: Man ! I found ! You were right all along. This is the url rewriting that stinks. By adding the "page" in the navigation.xml + the call without the rewrite, it works. There are no more calls to change the rewrite. Thank you.